# Definition of Forged

Tags: meaning, usage, definition

I am confused about how I can use the word 'forged' in my English essay.

Here is my sentence:

> Through building an undying bond with his son, forged through the omnipotence of love, they survive even the most savage of extremes.

When I looked up the definition of forged on google it said it meant a counterfeit. Yet you can forge a strong alliance - so can one forge a strong bond?

Comment: Look up **forge** again. It has two distinct meanings.

Comment: If you are still unsure after you have checked both meanings, please add a link to the dictionary entry that you are confused about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Forge" has two distinct meanings: To shape and strengthen metal by work and hammering and bending (usually when it is hot, but not molten) is one meaning and the other is "to make fake things".  The two meanings are quite distinct in English (although both come ultimately from Latin words meaning "make").

When we say "forge" in reference to a relationship it is a figurative usage, based on the meaning "shape and strengthen by work".

Comment: So can you forge a relationship out of love as I used it in my sentence or does distinct work need to occur?

Comment: @Jeko - you don't need a furnace, hammer and anvil.

Comment: "Forge" does suggest that there is work done to make the relationship.  It suggest that the "love" is natural raw material (like the iron) and the relationship is is the manufactured product (like a sword, or a candlestick or whatever, made by work and skill).  Note that in "forge a signature" is the literal second meaning of "forge".